# Alamofire post requestString cannot get the right token response

Tags: ios, swift, request, alamofire, response

I trying to make a post request with alamofire to get the access token for login, the thing is the response I get is a runtime error html page which seems a server error but this request is working in postman and also in android app the same request is working fine

here the response I get

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Runtime Error</title>
<meta name=“viewport” content=“width=device-width” />
<style>
 body {font-family:“Verdana”;font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
 p {font-family:“Verdana”;font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
 b {font-family:“Verdana”;font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
 H1 { font-family:“Verdana”;font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
 H2 { font-family:“Verdana”;font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
 pre {font-family:“Consolas”,“Lucida Console”,Monospace;font- 
 size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
 .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
 .version {color: gray;}
 .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
 .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
 @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
 pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
 }
 @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
 pre { width: 280px; }
 }
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor=“white”>
  <span><H1>Server Error in ‘/’ Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>
  <h2> <i>Runtime Error</i> </h2></span>
  <font face=“Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif “>
  <b> Description: </b>An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error 
   settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being 
 viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on 
the local server machine.
  <br><br>
  <b>Details:</b> To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on 
remote machines, please create a &lt;customErrors&gt; tag within a &quot;web.config&quot; 
configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This 
&lt;customErrors&gt; tag should then have its &quot;mode&quot; attribute set to 
&quot;Off&quot;.<br><br>
  <table width=100% bgcolor=“#FFFFCC”>
    <tr>
     <td>
       <code><pre>
&lt;!-- Web.Config Configuration File --&gt;
&lt;configuration&gt;
&lt;system.web&gt;
&lt;customErrors mode=&quot;Off&quot;/&gt;
&lt;/system.web&gt;
&lt;/configuration&gt;</pre></code>
     </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <b>Notes:</b> The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page 
  by modifying the &quot;defaultRedirect&quot; attribute of the application&#39;s 
  &lt;customErrors&gt; configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.<br><br>
  <table width=100% bgcolor=“#FFFFCC”>
    <tr>
     <td>
       <code><pre>
&lt;!-- Web.Config Configuration File --&gt;
&lt;configuration&gt;
&lt;system.web&gt;
&lt;customErrors mode=&quot;RemoteOnly&quot; 
defaultRedirect=&quot;mycustompage.htm&quot;/&gt;
&lt;/system.web&gt;
&lt;/configuration&gt;</pre></code>
     </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  <br>
 </body>
 </html>
```

and it looks like from the description the error is related to custom error messages which said its not viewed remotely, but actually I get the errors when for example if I enter invalid user name and password I get the error response that its invalid username or password and also other error responses, the only thing I dont get is the success response which is the access token

here my code, this is the alamofire manager

```
class AFManager : NSObject{

class func strRequestPOSTURL(_ strURL : String, params : [String : String]?, headers : 
[String : String]?, success:@escaping (JSON) -> Void, failure:@escaping (Error) -> Void){
    URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()

    Alamofire.request(strURL, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: 
   URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers).responseString { (response) in
        //print(response)

        if response.result.isSuccess {
            let resJson = JSON(response.result.value!)
            success(resJson)
        }
        if response.result.isFailure {
            let error : Error = response.result.error!
            let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode
            //print(statusCode as Any)
         
            failure(error)
        }
        
    }

  }
}
```

and here the call

```
func onLogin() {
    
    let progressHUD = ProgressHUD(text: NSLocalizedString("please_wait", comment: ""))
    self.view.addSubview(progressHUD)
    progressHUD.show()
   
    
    let parameters = ["Username": usernameTxt.textField.text!,
                      "password": passwordTxt.textField.text! ,
                      "Grant_type": "password" ,
                      "DeviceToken": mobileID ]
    let headers = ["Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]
  
    //print(parameters)
    if !AFManager.Connectivity.isConnectedToInternet {
        print("no internet is available.")
        AppDelegate.init().noInternetConnectionMsg(viewController: self)
    }
    
    AFManager.strRequestPOSTURL(URLs.URL_LOGIN, params: parameters as [String : 
 String],headers: headers ,success: { (JSONResponse) in
        progressHUD.hide()

        print("resss \(JSONResponse)")
        do{
            if let json = JSONResponse.stringValue.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8){
                if let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: json, options: 
 .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]{
                    
                    
                    
                    let errorResDesc = jsonData["error_description"] as? String
                    
                    if( (jsonData["error"] == nil) && (jsonData["error_description"] == nil)){
                      
                        if( (jsonData["access_token"] != nil) ){
                          let accessToken = JSONResponse["access_token"]
                          let accessTokenExpIn = JSONResponse["expires_in"]
                          
                          self.userDefaul.alreadyLoggedInBefore(x: 1)
                          
                          self.currentUser.accessToken = accessToken.stringValue
                          self.currentUser.accessTokenExpireIn = accessTokenExpIn.intValue
                          self.currentUser.nameStr = ""
                          self.currentUser.phoneStr = ""
                          self.currentUser.balance = 0.0
                          self.currentUser.emailStr = ""
                          self.currentUser.activationStatus = 0
                          
                          
                          //print("user \(String(describing: self.currentUser.accessToken))")
                          
                          
                          self.keyChainWrapper.setCurrentLoginUser(self.currentUser)
                          
                          self.getUserDetails(username: self.usernameTxt.textField.text!)
                        }
                          
                      }
                      else if (errorResDesc != nil){

                        let errorCod = jsonData["error"] as? String
                          //// this for taking the "block account error msg" and the "number of minits of blocking the
                        if ((errorResDesc!.contains(":"))){
                              
                            let msg = errorResDesc!.split(separator: ":")
                              //print(msg[0])
                            let min = msg[1].replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "")
                              //print(min)
                              
                            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: AFManager.changeMsg1(MsgCode: Int(errorCod!)!) + " " + min + NSLocalizedString("min", comment: ""), preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
                              alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("ok", comment: ""), style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
                              self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                              
                          }else
                          {
                              let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: AFManager.changeMsg1(MsgCode: Int(errorCod!)!), preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
                          alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("ok", comment: ""), style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
                          self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                          }
                      
                    }else{
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: NSLocalizedString("some_error_occured", comment: "") , preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
                                   alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("ok", comment: ""), style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
                                   self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }

                }
            }
        }catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)

        }
        
        
        
    }) { (error) in
        progressHUD.hide()
        print("error : \(error)")
        
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: NSLocalizedString("some_error_occured", comment: "") , preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("ok", comment: ""), style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
    
}
```

maybe I am doing something wrong with my code, and if there is something in backend to be change is it will affect the android app?
please help thanks in advance

### **EDIT**

here the code from postman, and I try it and its work

```
var semaphore = DispatchSemaphore (value: 0)

let parameters = "Username=rooh@mahaba.om&password=Rooh@1234&Grant_type=password&DeviceToken=541230"
let postData =  parameters.data(using: .utf8)

var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://my-web-app.azurewebsites.net/token")!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = postData

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in 
guard let data = data else {
print(String(describing: error))
return
  }
  print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
 semaphore.signal()
}

task.resume()
semaphore.wait()
```

How I can tell the differences ? In another word how I convert this request to be done by Alamofire?

Comment: If it works in POSTMAN, you ca use POSTMAN to generate Swift Code (or curl one), and check the different with yours.

Comment: @Larme how can I do that?

Comment: https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/ "POSTMAN Generate Code" in your favorite Search Engine would have save you time. Then, you can paste here the CURL (or the Swift code, it's not beautiful one, but sufficient) if you can't spot the difference.

Comment: @Larme ok I will try that thanks

Comment: @Larme I added the swift code from postman, if you can help me to know what wrong with my request please

Comment: OMG, I found out what was wrong, and I feel so stupid, the problem was in one of the parameters :\ in postman the parameter deviceToken is only numbers but in my code I was passing something like this "AA82EEAF-79B6-4F07-83DA-09DDD32F6A53" thats caused the problem